# "hostname -i" returns IP address of different network interface devices in various Linux hosts

Tags: linux, ip, hostname

In some Linux box it returns IP of the interface **eth0** and in some it returns IP assigned to **eth1** device, and in some it returns all the IPs assigned to all the network interfaces available in that system

```
$ hostname -i
*192.168.0.58  192.168.0.59  192.168.0.60*
```

I do not understand why it is happening this way and how to configure this command to return only the IP of a particular network interface (only)?

Please note, there is no **strace** utility in the production servers to check the call trace
And, the **inet** string is found in almost all the network interfaces

Comment: in man hostname: "Note that this works only if the host name can be resolved. Avoid  using  this option;". Can your hostname be resolved?

Comment: Yes, `nslookup` and `dig` resolves atleast one IP in the list returned in case if more than one IP is returned from the `hostname -i`

Comment: I can see one IP entry listed by `hostname -i` is not found in the `/etc/hosts` file